# Radio buttons, true or false

Tags: grails, controller, radio-button, gsp

I've just met with a problem on how to use radio buttons. So this is my codes:
In GSP

```
 <g:each in="${Query1}">
 <label for="account_expired">Account Expired:</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="acc_expired" value="${it.acc_exp}" checked="checked"> True
              <input type="radio" name="acc_expired" value="${it.acc_exp}"> False
<br />
</g:each>
```

In my controller:

```
if(params.username != null )
    {
    String updateQuery = "UPDATE sec_user SET account_locked='"+params.account_locked+"'  WHERE Username='"+params.username+"'"


    String queryname = "select * from sec_user where username = '"+params.username+"'"
    def Query1 = sql.rows(queryname)

    def update = sql.executeUpdate(updateQuery)

    [update:update, Query1:Query1]

    }
```

So, what I'm trying to do is how does the radio button check which values goes to which 'checked' radio button. Because I'm doing an edit page, so the controller will retrieve information from the database and auto select the radio button, whether is it 'True' or 'False'. In this case it's either '1' or '0'. So is there anyone out there can help me with this?

Thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have your view correctly check the radio you want, you need to add an expression to your tag. Also I suspect you don't want each button to have the same value. I'm guessing one should be true and the other false.

```
<input type="radio" name="acc_expired" value="${true}" ${it.acc_exp == true ? 'checked="checked"' : ''}> True
<input type="radio" name="acc_expired" value="${false}" ${it.acc_exp == false ? 'checked="checked"' : ''}> False
```

PS. You may want to look up SQL Injection.

Comment: the variable in the value ${true}. Do I need to place it in the controller or something?

Comment: true is not a variable, it's a Java keyword for the boolean value of true, available in any expression.

Comment: Oh it worked already, thank you so much! Anyway, why do you want me to look up on SQL injections?

Comment: Directly inserting user input into a sql query is unsafe

Comment: oh i see.. hmm, I've researched on it.. but is there a proper way of sanitizing it?

Comment: Sorry, another question. In your code there is a '?'. May I know what it means? I stumbled upon this for many times when I'm reading source codes.

Answer (score 0):

will you explain it specifically ,However This may help you http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/radioGroup.html

```
boolean[] acc_expired= [] //in your controller
```

and iterate this array to get their checked or unchecked index.

Comment: Okay for example the radio buttons is either true or false. So, now in the controller, I've got to select the query from the database and transfer it to radio button. If let's say the query result is '1'. Radio button true will be 'checked'. But how does the radio button or controller determine which radio button is checked? Do you understand what I'm trying to say?

Comment: just put this array of type boolean. Remember the name of this array must be the name of your radio button. // like this boolean[] acc_expired= []

Comment: Do you have an example? Because I'm quite confused with how it works. okay wait, i show you my full code on how the update and select works.